# excel vba function return array and paste in worksheet formula

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, formula

Is it possible for an vba function to return array values and paste in the sheet with excel formula?

For example, I want to write a formula in excel cell say A1 like `=GetData()` and press enter. It returns 4 metrics with A1:A4,B1:B4 cells filled in.

I tried Variant and Collection as return types. The values are there but it only populates the first cell.

```
Function GetData(Input1 As Range) As Variant       
    Dim value() As Variant
    value(1, 1) = "somevalue"
    value(1, 2) = "somevalue"
    ............
    value(2, 2) = "somevalue"

    GetData = value
End Function
```

Comment: I believe that if you return an array, you have to select multiple cells and press shift-enter in order to get all those values. You can use index() to get the specific values within the array such as: =INDEX(A1:A4,3)

Comment: Read this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code:

```
Function GetData() As Variant
    Dim value(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
    value(1, 1) = "1;1"
    value(1, 2) = "1;2"
    value(2, 1) = "2;1"
    value(2, 2) = "somevalue"
    GetData = value
End Function
```

Select cells **D1** through **E2**; then click in the Formula Bar; then enter:

```
=getdata()
```

as an array formula:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

**EDIT#1:**

As *Jeeped* pointed out, once the formulas have been array-entered in this fashion, a single cell in the array cannot be changed by itself.  So:

```
Range("D1").Clear
```

will fail.  You would need:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    Dim r As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r = Range("D1")
    Set r2 = r.CurrentArray
    r2.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: The range of cells (2 rows by 2 columns) also gets 'locked' so that any changes must be made to all the cells in the range; you cannot make a change to a single cell.

Comment: @Jeeped  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I don't know the number of rows the function returns. Number of columns is predefined. How do I set row range dynamic?

Comment: @siz  You would use a **Sub** rather than a **Function**.  The sub can make its own decisions about where its output goes.

Comment: Ok, how do i call a sub from excel formula?

Comment: Please note I don't want to add macros to the workbook. This is excel add-in.

Comment: If you use a function or a formula then its up to the user to define the extent of the cells receiving the output.........that how functions work.

Answer (score 0):

Use join to convert array to string, check Cell properties>Wrap text. then you can populate array to single cell.

```
Value(0) = "somedata"
value(1) = "somedata"
GetData = Join(value, Chr(10))
```